# Symbian via C#

Tags: c#, mobile

Is it posible to build programs using C# for Symbian ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. If you use the Net60 app from https://www.redfivelabs.com/default.aspx

You have to pay for it though. I don't think there is a free or open source version

There are also plans by Microsoft and Nokia to have [Silverlight on Symbian Devices](http://betalabs.nokia.com/apps/silverlight)

Answer (score 1):

A quick google tells me the answer is "no".
http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-11171.html

Apparently there was a company called AppForge that created a product that allowed compiling C# into Symbian apps. After Oracle acquired them, it appears that this product is [defunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppForge#Effect_of_insolvency_on_AppForge_CrossFire_Users_And_Possible_Solutions).