# .Net framework for symbian

Tags: .net, frameworks, symbian

Is there any .Net framework for making symbian application?

Comment: See this question: (Kind of a duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597665/symbian-via-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about something for Series 60 symbian phones. You can see the details here: http://www.symbian-freak.com/news/007/03/net_compact_framework.htm

Answer (score 0):

No. Only for iOS (iPhone) and Android. They're called MonoTouch and MonoDroid.

And of course, for Windows Mobile and Windows Phone 7.

If you want to do Symbian you're stuck with C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Nokia has built a Silverlight runtime. You would be restricted to the Silverlight subset of .NET, however. See http://betalabs.nokia.com/apps/silverlight